# Postgres data type cast

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, casting

My database is Postgres 8. I need to cast data type to another. That means, one of columns data type is `varchar` and need to cast it into `int` with Postgres in a `SELECT` statement.

Currently, I get the string value and cast it into `int` in Java.
Is there any way to do it? Sample code would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Just FYI, saying "PostgreSQL 8" is a bit like saying "Windows 6". Windows XP is 5.1 (or 5.2 for x64), Vista is 6.0 and Windows 7 is 6.1. They're all pretty different! It's the same with PostgreSQL; there's 5 years and a huge technical difference between PostgreSQL 8.0 and 8.4, so please always specify the *full* version.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

```
cast(varchar_col AS int)  -- SQL standard
```

or

```
varchar_col::int          -- Postgres syntax shorthand
```

Theses syntax variants are valid (almost) *anywhere*. The second may require nesting parentheses in special situations:

- [PostgreSQL: Create index on length of all table fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34143116/postgresql-create-index-on-length-of-all-table-fields/34144962#34144962)

And the first may be required where only functional notation is allowed by syntax restrictions:

- [PostgreSQL - CAST vs :: operator on LATERAL table function](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/280410/3684)

There are two more variants:

```
int4(varchar_col)         -- only works for some type names
int '123'                 -- must be an untyped, quoted string literal
```

Note how I wrote ***`int4`***`(varchar_col)`. That's the internal type name and there is also a function defined for it. Wouldn't work as <strike>`integer()`</strike> or <strike>`int()`</strike>.

Note also that the last form does not work for *array* types. <strike>`int[] '{1,2,3}'`</strike> has to be `'{1,2,3}'::int[]` or `cast('{1,2,3}' AS int[])`.

Details in the manual [**here**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS) and [**here**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS-GENERIC).

To be valid for `integer`, the string must be comprised of an optional leading sign (`+`/`-`) followed by digits only. Leading / trailing white space is ignored.

Comment: it doesn't work if the *column* is of *character* data type

Comment: @AbelMelquiadesCallejo: What is "it"? All of the above works for data type `character` (except where explicitly noted). The string must be a valid integer, of course.