# What does :: do in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, syntax, types, casting, typecast-operator

I have seen `::` in variety of places involving postgres code I have seen on the net. For example:

```
SELECT '{apple,cherry apple, avocado}'::text[];
```

It seems to be some sort of cast. What exactly is `::` in postgres and when should it be used?

I tried a bit of googling and searched the Postgres docs for `::` but got no good results.
I tried following searches in Google:

- postgres double colon
- postgres ::
- ::

I tried the following searches in the postgres docs search button

- double colon
- double colon cast
- ::

This was almost embarrassing to ask on SO, but I figured Google will hopefully see this answer for other people in the future.

Comment: It is a cast ("type coercion")

Comment: I'm surprised you didn't spot the answer in a search. See the first few hits in the following search: https://www.google.com/search?q=postgresql+double+colon . Can you tell me what you searched for so I can try to make the relevant part of the docs easier to find?

Comment: @CraigRinger I updated the question with the search that I ran, as best as I can remember them.

Comment: This question and answers are much more to the point than the "original". The other one should have been closed.

Comment: @ams Thanks for the detailed update, I hope it helps others in future.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

A type cast specifies a conversion from one data type to another.

PostgreSQL accepts two equivalent syntaxes for type casts, the PostgreSQL-specific `value::type` and the SQL-standard `CAST(value AS type)`.

In this specific case, `'{apple,cherry apple, avocado}'::text[];` takes the string literal `{apple,cherry apple, avocado}` and tells PostgreSQL to interpret it as an *array of `text`*.

See the documentation on [SQL expressions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html) and [arrays](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html) for details.

Answer (score 15):

[What @PSR and @Craig wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15537761/939860).
Plus, there are *two more syntax variants*:

1. `type value`

This form only casts constants (string literals). Like in:

```
SELECT date '2013-03-21';
```

More in the manual in the chapter [**Constants of Other Types**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS-GENERIC).

2. `type(value)`

That's the function-like syntax. Works only for types whose names are valid as function names. Like in:

```
SELECT date(date_as_text_col) FROM tbl;
```

More in the manual in the chapter [**Type Casts**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS).

**More comprehensive answer:**

- [Postgres data type cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13676816/postgres-data-type-cast/13676871#13676871)

Comment: Good point, though that isn't really a *type cast*, it's part of the syntax for specifying a literal. You can't write `DATE somecolumn`, only `DATE '2012-01-01'`; ie it has to be `TYPENAME 'literalvalue'`.

Comment: @CraigRinger: Excellent point. I was actually being imprecise. Clarified my post and added a bit.