# :: operator in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've come across the `::` operator in `PostgreSQL`. Since google's finding such symbols not very I've not found what it means. For instance,

```
SELECT *
FROM player_account 
WHERE '2014-11-11'::date >= now()::date 
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: The trick was to search for "double colon" rather than the symbol itself

Comment: I searched on "postgres double colon" and found this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15537709/what-does-do-in-postgresql