# How to update date column in partitions of n rows?

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime

I am trying to update my date field.
Table structure is like:

```
date           id 
2016-11-14     1
2016-11-14     2
2016-11-14     3
2016-11-14     4
-
-
-
2016-11-14     100
```

How to update first ten records with different date, second ten records with different date and so on?

Comment: what data type is `date`? and what would be the new value?

Comment: timestamp with time zone

Comment: Then it's not a date field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a CASE

```
  UPDATE yourTable
  SET "date" = CASE WHEN id <= 10 then '2016-11-01'::timestamp 
                    WHEN id <= 20 then '2016-11-02'::timestamp 
                    ....
                    WHEN id <= 100 then '2016-11-10'::timestamp 
               END;
```

Comment: I am getting error like "column "date" is of type date but expression is of type text"

Comment: add `::timestamp ` or something similar dependin on your `"date"` type Check edit.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE tbl t
SET   "date" = date '2016-11-14' + sub.rn::int / 10  -- integer division
FROM  (
   SELECT id, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS rn
   FROM   tbl
   ) sub
WHERE t.id =  sub.id;
```

The subquery computes a gapless row number, since nothing in your question says the `id` is actually guaranteed to be without gaps.

You can just add an `integer` to an actual `date` to add a days. (Forgot the cast to `int` in my first version.)

For `timestamp` use instead:

```
timestamp '2016-11-14' + interval '1 day' * (sub.rn / 10)
```

Comment: Sorry i am not able to achieve it.I am getting error here  "ERROR:  operator does not exist: date + bigint
LINE 2: SET   date = date '2016-11-14' + (sub.rn / 10) "

Comment: need something like this `'2016-11-30'::timestamp + INTERVAL sub.rn || ' day' END;`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza: Wouldn't work with `timestamp` - where I would use the expression `timestamp '2016-11-14 0:0' + interval '1 day' * (sub.rn / 10)` - but that's not the question.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter still have some error. http://rextester.com/LAAQ86247

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza: No, I don't. Your test incorrectly uses `timestamp` instead of `date`. I already told you that's wrong. This is the right test: http://rextester.com/LAAQ86247

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter you send the same link. In rextester you need to press `save` to generate the new link. Now we know OP was talking about `timestamp` maybe irrelvant, but still will  like to know how looks like, because dont use `date` very often.

Comment: nevermind I did it myself. Q: is there a difference between  `date '2016-11-14' `  and `'2016-11-14' ::date`, I knew the second one, the result look the same, dont know why have two sintaxis for the same.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza: Sorry, pasted the old link. Here is the new link: http://rextester.com/GKIPQ42219. A: There is a very minor difference. The 1st one casts the literal to `date` directly. The 2nd one defaults to type `text` and is *then* cast to `date`. So `date '2016-11-14'` is a tiny bit faster and 1 character shorter. You won't be able to measure the difference. Details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13676871/939860