# Can't get the name of a related table column

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, types

I'm just starting to learn SQL, and so far (since two days ago) i managed to solve most of my problems, but now i need help.

The query below results in 1 column and row: "12345" and some extra rows with the value 0, that i need to get rid of.

```
SELECT product_id FROM sale_order_line WHERE order_id IN (SELECT id FROM sale_order WHERE name='S00062')
```

So i tried the following:

```
SELECT product_id FROM sale_order_line WHERE order_id IN (SELECT id FROM sale_order WHERE name='S00062') AND NOT product_id='0'
```

And now i get the result '12345' i was expecting.
But when i try to get the **name** of the the column related to '12345' from another table....:

```
SELECT name FROM product_template WHERE product_variant_ids IN (SELECT product_id FROM sale_order_line WHERE order_id IN (SELECT id FROM sale_order WHERE name='S00062') AND NOT product_id='0')
```

I get an error saying: *"Cannot compare data type of integer to string"*.
Somehow it appears the code above tries to read **product_id** with all the 0s before they're all removed. I'm guessing.

But, if i do it directly, like:

```
SELECT name FROM product_template WHERE product_variant_ids = '12345'
```

It works!
How can i fix this?
Please forgive my newbie coding skills.

Comment: Please provide your version of Postgres and basic table definitions (`CREATE TABLE` statements showing data types and constraints) with any quession like this.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I actually don't know my postgresql version. Can i check it from SQL? I'm accessing my company ERP (ODOO), online version, which i'm just begining to understand the database structure and i need to extract some data that i can't from the ERP itself. So i'm using a Python connector for it. So basically i need to extract data from a database i don't know, with a programming language i don't know also...

Comment: Ask Postgres: `SELECT version();`

Comment: It returned Unknown function version.

Comment: *No* Postgres version would say that. Looks like you are using a different RDBMS.

Comment: It's a connector to the ERP. It has plenty of limitations. I can't make more than one query at once, for example.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that `product_template.product_variant_ids` and `sale_order_line.product_id` are of incompatible data type, one of `integer` and the other a string type (`text`, `varchar`, ...) -  as the error message indicates.

Make it a habit to table-qualify all column names in queries involving multiple columns.

Guessing from the column names, `product_id` is `integer`, and `product_variant_ids` is a string type, which is most probably a design error. If it actually holds a single valid integer in string representation, like your final query suggests, then making some more assumptions about PK constraints in your data model, your query could work like this:

```
SELECT pt.name
FROM   sale_order       so
JOIN   sale_order_line  sol ON sol.order_id = so.id
JOIN   product_template pt  ON pt.product_variant_ids::int = sol.product_id  -- !
WHERE  so.name = 'S00062'
AND    NOT sol.product_id = 0;  -- numeric literal without
```

Note the cast to integer: `product_variant_ids::int`. But this is just putting lipstick on a pig. The column should be type `integer` to begin with.

Then again, the name `product_variant_ids` indicates multiple values, hinting at `int[]`, an array of integer. Then you need to do more ...

Use `JOIN` notation instead of nesting multiple levels of `x IN (subquery)`. Much simpler, and typically much faster.

Both are identical as long as the subquery returns distinct values. Else, the `IN` notation folds duplicates, while joins do not. This difference also makes `x IN (subquery)` more sophisticated to execute internally and hence more expensive.

Finally, a column named `product_variant_ids` typically indicates misguided database design in any case. Typically, you don't cram multiple values in a single column. If that column has a string type on top of it, that's a double no-no. You have to look into relational design and database normalization some more.

Comment: I'm still in the process of understanding your code :) but, and although i know very very little of SQL, i agree with you in what i could understand.
I have used JOIN notations in other queries, but i found it more confusing to 'read'. And since i can only use one query per time, i used subqueries. But i'll do better next time.
I think the connector limitations will be the biggest problem. When i ran your script now, i got the error: "Invalid column name 'product_variant_ids::int' for table 'product_template'."

Comment: @Telmo: Again, not a Postgres error message. This is Postgres-specific cast syntax. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13676871/939860 Try with standard SQL  `ON cast(pt.product_variant_ids AS integer) = sol.product_id`. But find out the exact RDBMS and version you are dealing with before you proceed. Makes no sense this way ...