# Lower bound for Postgres integer type out of range?

Tags: sql, postgresql, syntax, casting, integer

Per Postgres [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-TABLE), an `integer` type is defined between `-2147483648` and `+2147483647`.
I thought that these boundaries were inclusive, but if I try:

```
select -2147483648 = -2147483648::int4
```

an `Integer out of range error` is raised.

The upper bound seems to be casted properly:

```
# select 2147483647 = 2147483647::int4;
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

And if I increase the lower bound by one it works fine as well:

```
# select -2147483647 = -2147483647::int4;
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

The same result is applied to `smallint`.
Is there something obvious that I'm missing here, or are lower bounds excluded for Postgres numeric types?

Comment: `select -2147483648::int4` fails, but interestingly `select cast(-2147483648 as int4)` works.

Comment: @TheImpaler interesting...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR**: [**operator precedence**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-PRECEDENCE).

This is tricky at first sight. The same cast of the lower bound seemingly fails for `smallint` and `bigint`, too:

```sql
SELECT -32768::int2; -- fails
SELECT -2147483648::int4; -- fails
SELECT -9223372036854775808::int8; -- fails
```

But looks are deceiving. This is what really happens:

```
SELECT - (2147483648::int4);
```

`-` is taken to be *"unary minus"* operator, which only kicks in ***after*** `::` (the *"PostgreSQL-style typecast"*). And since the range of `integer` (`int4`) is
`-2147483648 to +2147483647` as you quoted accurately, the expression fails at:

```
SELECT 2147483648::int4;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=d57dde48c819284f1ade0b1e8d3f6ced)*

Use one of these instead:

```
SELECT '-2147483648'::int4;
SELECT int '-2147483648';
```

Also ever so slightly more *efficient*, since that's just a cast, not a cast + negation operation.

You could even:

```
SELECT (-2147483648)::int4;
```

Just to overrule operator precedence. But the last one looks awkward. And it's slightly less efficient. :)

Related:

- [Postgres data type cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13676816/postgres-data-type-cast/13676871#13676871)