# Turn character varying column from null to 0

Tags: postgresql, coalesce

If I have a table like this:

[image: Screenshot]

How can I turn all NULL values to 0?
Using:

```
SELECT coalesce(area::text, 0) as area,
       coalesce(duration::text, 0) as duration
```

But it keeps saying:

> COALESCE types text and integer cannot be matched.

Comment: `SELECT coalesce(area, '0') as area, coalesce(duration, '0') as duration,`

Comment: Cast that 0 to text (Or just quote it) or duration to integer.

Comment: The true solution is to repair your broken table design and use a [numeric type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html) for your numeric `data` in area and `duration`. Then your original query works, too. But read up on [data type casts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13676871/939860) as well.