# How to combine 2 SELECT statements with different returning data-types in 1 query?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, select, psycopg2

I have tried using `UNION ALL` query, but it needs the same returning data-type. In the example below `name` is `TEXT` while `debits` is `json` it leads to an error with `UNION ALL`-

So how do I return the combined result of `name` and `debits` in one query ?

```
'''
    (SELECT
    name
    FROM
    mytable
    WHERE grade= % s)
    UNION
    ALL
    (SELECT
    debits
    FROM
    mytable
    WHERE balancesheet= % s)
    ;
    '''
```

> psycopg2.errors.DatatypeMismatch: UNION types text and json cannot be matched .

Answer (score 1):

Like you stated correctly, and the error msg instructs: you need compatible types. One way to solve it: convert `text` to `json` with [`to_json()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE):

```sql
SELECT to_json(name) AS name_and_debit
FROM   mytable
WHERE  grade = %s

UNION ALL
SELECT debits
FROM   mytable
WHERE  balancesheet = %s
;
```

Or `json` to `text` with a plain cast: `debits::text`. See:

- [Postgres data type cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13676816/postgres-data-type-cast/13676871#13676871)

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! I have bool and other data types as well , Is there a cleaner way to do this than type casting ? Selecting multiple rows  must be a very basic operation .

Comment: @shadow: Either return separate columns (can remain NULL for rows that don't contribute), or you need a common data type, as the same result column can only have *one* data type. Use `text` if in doubt. Every type can be cast to `text`.